# How can I get the normal Google Maps blue current location marker?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I know how i can get my current location and how to place a marker on given coordinates. What I am trying to figure out is how I can get that blue round current location marker that you get in your normal Google Maps app. Which moves as the device changes location fluently without any lag and shows you the direction you are facing. I will add an image to make it clearer. I am guessing it also uses some sort of animation to show the changing location fluently. I am working on AndroidStudio.

[image]

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147350/google-maps-current-location-marker-period-updates-for-gmaps/38147659#38147659

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

did the trick for me.