# How to replace or remove the circle around my location blue dot for Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

Uber released an update to their app, and they have somehow made the circle around the my location blue dot pulsate.

Here is an image (not an Uber screenshot) of the blue dot and circle I am talking about:

[image]

My question is not about Ubers' implementation, my question is that I did not believe it was possible to remove the blue circle from google maps. How is this done? If I know this, I can use animations at my current location to achieve the same effect.

I have already attempted doing the following

```
gmaps.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

This had no effect on the blue dot, nor the blue circle around the dot.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147350/google-maps-current-location-marker-period-updates-for-gmaps/38147659#38147659

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The blue circle should be removed with

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Heh, not sure why I did not try that. This gets me closer.